# How to use multiple Django FBVs in capturing and saving data through Ajax+jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

In my Django app, I am using two function views, FV1 and FV2.

FV1 is being used to capture data from the database and populate form/formsets.

In FV2, I am trying to send serialized data from the page (with the aforesaid data) using Ajax, validate the data in FV2 and save it and finally, receive a confirmation from FV2 as Ajax callback in the page.

In the console I can see the serialized data. That validation happens is proven by the fact that if one of the required values is not keyed in, error message captured in the relevant `else:` segment is passed to the console.

However, if all the data is correctly entered and form is submitted, data is not being saved in the respective models. There is no error message either.

Given the above scenario, what should be the approach in achieving the goal. It goes without saying that I am missing something big. A guidance to solving the problem will be much appreciated.

**Edit**

### models.py:

```
class mapTarg(models.Model):
    map_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Map ID')
    map_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Map name')
    map_target = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Target')

class mapTargItems(models.Model):
    map_itm = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Item')
    map_hdr = models.ForeignKey(mapTarg, related_name='map_hdr_tab', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Mapper')
    map_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Target Fld')
    map_field_col = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Col')
```

### views.py:

```
def SaveMapAjax(request, object_id=False):
    if object_id:
        qs_targ_model_form = mapTarg.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    else:
        qs_targ_model_form = mapTarg()

    target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset()

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        new_qs_targ_model_form = mappedTargModelForm(data=request.POST, instance=qs_targ_model_form)

        if new_qs_targ_model_form.is_valid():
            qs_targ_model_form = new_qs_targ_model_form.save(commit=False)
            target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(request.POST, instance=qs_targ_model_form)

            if target_field_formset.is_valid():
                qs_targ_model_form.save()
                target_field_formset.save()

            msg='Data saved!'

        else:
            msg= 'Error occured..'
    return JsonResponse(msg, safe=False)
```

### ajax fucntion

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSaveMap').on('click', function() {    // "Save" button
    var frm = $('#dataMapperForm');              // Form id

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: '{% url 'save_mapper' %}',      // Url pointing to view for saving data
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success !!');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('Problemo');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked out Django Rest Framework? It will save you a lot of time, is extremely mature and very well documented. On another note, it is nigh impossible to help without seeing your code. If you can include both your FBVs and your models it should be possible for people to help you.

Comment: @anowlinorbit - Added the codes. Checking out REST in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, that is that you want to create an instance of a `mapTargItem` with the FK point to an instance of `mapTarg`, then I would create viewsets in DRF. I'll start with the serializers. This is a very common pattern in DRF

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import mapTarg, mapTargItems

class mapTargItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mapTarg
        fields = "__all__"
        # if you want to only return a select number of model attributes
        # then you can as an example define fields as follows
        # fields = ("map_name", "map_target")

class mapTargSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    map_hdr_tab = mapTargItemsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = mapTarg
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```py
from .serializers import mapTargItemsSerializer, mapTargSerializer
from .models import mapTarg, mapTargItems


class mapTargItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = mapTargItemsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = mapTargItems.objects.all()

    # you can override get_queryset() for more advanced queries


class mapTargViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = mapTargSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = mapTarg.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```py
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import mapTargViewSet, mapTargItemsViewSet

router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register("map_targs", mapTargViewSet, basename="map_targs")
router.register("map_targ_items", mapTargItemsViewSet, basename="map_targ_items")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

You can now hit the endpoint for `map_targs`, get the object you want to use as the FK for `mapTargItems` then POST to `map_targ_items`.

DRF will handle the validation, serialization and response for you and return sensible error messages should any errors occurs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to write this. I am certainly going to use this in future. But at the moment this is not going to work in my current scenario. As I have described, I am using Django formsets which I am populating using data from various models. The forms are nicely lined up and using jQuery I am able to add additional formsets at **runtime**. I would very much comprehend this as any **normal** Django inline formset scenario for creating records in related models. So my problem is - **How do I send this data (residing in the form and formsets) to the respective models.**?